# mod_dir Redirect behind load balancer with wrong port

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

I am having an issue with the redirect that occurs with mod_dir when a trailing slash is missing. Our setup uses a load balancer listening on port 80 with multiple web servers that listen on non-standard ports like 8081.

When mod_dir issues the redirect it is attempting to redirect to domain.com:8081/path/ which of course times out.

I have tried setting UseCanonicalName On and specifying ServerName to include the port like so: domain.com:80 but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

My virtual host is as follows:

```
Listen 8081
<VirtualHost *:8081>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/domain_static
        UseCanonicalName Off
        ServerName domain.com:80

        <Directory /var/www/domain_static>
                Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride all
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/static-error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/static-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

What can I do to resolve this incorrect redirect behavior?

Comment: Your load balancer is where you can account for this behavior - either by manipulating the `Host` header sent to the port 8081 listener, or rewriting the `Location` header in the response.  What software does it run?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following:

```
ServerName domain.com
UseCanonicalName On
UseCanonicalPhysicalPort Off
```

I think `UseCanonicalPhysicalPort Off` is the important line.